# Node js request communication

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a `localhost 1337` server and a `3000` server

`1337` The server is sending data.
`3000` The server is the receiving place.

`1337` Send the data from the server
I want to get it from the `3000` server

It's the `1337` source first.

```
router.get('/send', function (req, res, next) {
    var params = req.query; //post일때 사용
    console.log(params);

    // res.status(200).send({input:params});

    request('http://localhost:3000/', function (error, response, body) {
        console.log("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
        console.log('error:', error);
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
        console.log('body:', params);
    });
});
```

Here we go to the `3000` server.

My data is also recorded in the LOG

But I do not think I'm going to log in, connect to the `3000` server, and send the data.

And `3000` server source.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
     res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
     var params = req.query;
     console.log("333333333333333333333333333333333333333333");
     console.log(params);
});
```

TITLE on the `3000` server and `33333333333` on the `CONSOLE.LOG`
I want to receive data from `1337`!

Let me know the right way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also a beginner in Node, so this might not be the correct/most efficient way to do this. However, I've managed to connect a local webapp to a local Node server and pass data using Express, like so:

```
// server.js

var express    = require('express'),
    cors       = require('cors'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000; 

http.createServer(app).listen(port, function (err) {
      con.connect(function() {
        console.log("Listening in port " + port);
      });
    });
```

This sets the server up for listening to requests, and now you can do something to specific requests, like:

```
app.post('/users', function(req,res) { 
  //Do something when receiving a POST request in "https://localhost:3000/users", like...
  console.log(req.body); //... print the request content
});
```

Then all you have to do is send a request via GET/POST on your local server, and it should work.

Here is Express documentation, explaining some of the stuff it can do:
http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Hope this helps!